# Maven mvn install doesn't run liquibase scripts

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

everyone! I faced with a problem. I have SpringBoot app with Spring JDBC and liquibase.
When I do **mvn install** my tests failed because, liquibase doesn't run. What is a problem?
Liquibase work correctly. When I use **liquibase:update** or just run an application - everything is fine.
I use mySQL db for app and for test too.
I even don't know what code you need to look.

In this way I connect to db for test:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringJdbcConfig {
    @Bean
    DataSource getDataSource() throws SQLException {
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("correct_db");
        dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
        dataSource.setPort(3306);
        dataSource.setUser("bestuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("bestuser");
        dataSource.setServerTimezone("UTC");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(getDataSource());
    }
```

Comment: did you bind your liquibase:update goal to one phase (eg: integration-test) in the pom.xml ?

Comment: @NoDataFound thank you. But I don't know how to set it. I have multi-modules structures. And plugin config is located in rest-app.  If I located in main pom, I have the following error: 
The file rest-app/src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml was not found in. 
Maybe, I write the incorrect path?

Answer (score 0):

Running Liquibase through the Maven plugin and through the Spring integration are completely separate ways of running liquibase, even if both are often triggered by a call to Maven.

When you run `mvn liquibase:update` you are calling into the `liquibase-maven-plugin` you have configured in the `<plugins>` section of your pom file. It's running as a particular step of your Maven build, like `compile` or `package`

Alternately, you can configure your Spring application to automatically run the Liquibase update logic when the spring application starts up. You may be starting your Spring app via something in Maven, but it's still Spring that is triggering Liquibase at that point.

If you are not seeing any errors in your application startup about the Liquibase update operation failing, it may be because you don't have Liquibase as a dependency in your actual application. Even if you have the liquibase-maven-plugin plugin configured, you still need to add a

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

dependency for your application for Liquibase to run within it.